# I am doing sqoop import by using free form query and by using where condition

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

case 1: sqoop import using free form query:
   --query " select * from emp where id>500"

case 2: sqoop import using where condition:
    --table emp --where "id>500"

which one is faster and why?

Answer (score 0):

Query-2 will be faster than the query-1. Query-1 can't use the database catalog to fetch the metadata of the table. The fetched metadata is used to create a class dynamically which is used in the MapReduce which runs for the query internally.

However, Query-2 uses the database catalog to fetch the metadata of the table
This is one of the reasons why Query-2 is faster than the Query-1